# Create a setter to provide a java List Implementation class

Tags: java, generics, java-7, type-conversion, java-5

I'm writing a small type-conversion framework, based on this interface:

```java
public interface Converter <From,To> {
    public To convert(final From from);
}
```

So that I can write custom type converters such as

```java
public class BigDecimal2Double implements Converter<BigDecimal, Double> {

    @Override
    public Double convert(final BigDecimal value) {
        return value != null ? value.doubleValue() : null;
    }
}
```

The following class is intended to extend the capability of a converter, to deal with Lists of data..

```java
public abstract class ListConverter<From,To> implements Converter<From,To> {

    public List<To> convertList(List<From> fromList){

        if (fromList == null) {return null;}
        List<To> toList = new ArrayList<>(); // DEFAULT IMPLEMENTATION

        for(From from: fromList ){
            toList.add(this.convert(from));
        }

        return toList;
    }

    public static <From,To> ListConverter<From, To> extend(final Converter<From, To> converter){
        return new ListConverter<From, To>() {

            @Override
            public To convert(From from) {
                return converter.convert(from);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Thus I can write client code such as:

```java
ListConverter<BigDecimal,Double> lcb2d = ListConverter.extend(new BigDecimal2Double());
List<BigDecimal> bdList = retrieveSomeBigDecList();
List<Double> convertedList = lcb2d.convertList(bdList);
```

As you can see this can only provide a default `ArrayList` implementation for the converted list.

I would like to add the capability to provide a different `List` implementation from the client code, e.g:

```java
ListConverter<BigDecimal,Double> lcb2d = ListConverter.extend(new BigDecimal2Double());
List<BigDecimal> bdList = retrieveSomeBigDecList();
lcbd.setToListImplementation(LinkedList.class); // How to define such a method?
List<Double> convertedList = lcb2d.convertList(bdList); // would be a LinkedList
```

How could I accomplish that? 
The following code inside `ListConverter` class doesn't compile:

```java
private Class<? extends List<To>> toListImplementation = ArrayList.class;
public void setToListImplementation(Class<? extends List<To>> listImpl){
    toListImplementation = listImpl;
}
```

Also how should I replace this line, using the `toListImpl` private field?

```java
//... OLD
List<To> toList = new ArrayList<>(); // DEFAULT IMPLEMENTATION
//... NEW 
List<To> toList = toListImplementation.newInstance(); // WOULD WORK???
```

Edit: Java 8 is very cool, I know there are great features. 
I still work on java 7 though and I would like to accomplish java 5 compliance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide a way for a user of class `ListConverter` to supply a factory method to create the specific kind of `List` that is needed. Example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public abstract class ListConverter<From, To> implements Converter<From, To> {

    private final Supplier<List<To>> listFactory;

    public ListConverter(Supplier<List<To>> listFactory) {
        this.listFactory = listFactory;
    }

    public List<To> convertList(List<From> fromList) {
        if (fromList == null) {
            return null;
        }

        List<To> toList = listFactory.get();
        for (From from : fromList) {
            toList.add(this.convert(from));
        }

        return toList;
    }

    public static <From, To> ListConverter<From, To> extend(Converter<From, To> converter, Supplier<List<To>> listFactory) {
        return new ListConverter<From, To>(listFactory) {

            @Override
            public To convert(From from) {
                return converter.convert(from);
            }
        };
    }

    public static <From, To> ListConverter<From, To> extend(Converter<From, To> converter) {
        return extend(converter, ArrayList::new);
    }
}
```

If you would for example want a `LinkedList` then you could do:

```
ListConverter<BigDecimal,Double> lcb2d =
        ListConverter.extend(new BigDecimal2Double(), LinkedList::new);
```

**edit** - For Java 5-7, you can create a `ListFactory` interface:

```
import java.util.List;

public interface ListFactory<T> {
    List<T> newList();
}
```

And then use that, and use anonymous inner classes instead of Java 8 method references:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class ListConverter<From, To> implements Converter<From, To> {

    private final ListFactory<To> listFactory;

    public ListConverter(ListFactory<To> listFactory) {
        this.listFactory = listFactory;
    }

    public List<To> convertList(List<From> fromList) {
        if (fromList == null) {
            return null;
        }

        List<To> toList = listFactory.newList();
        for (From from : fromList) {
            toList.add(this.convert(from));
        }

        return toList;
    }

    public static <From, To> ListConverter<From, To> extend(Converter<From, To> converter, ListFactory<To> listFactory) {
        return new ListConverter<From, To>(listFactory) {
            @Override
            public To convert(From from) {
                return converter.convert(from);
            }
        };
    }

    public static <From, To> ListConverter<From, To> extend(Converter<From, To> converter) {
        return extend(converter, new ListFactory<To>() {
            @Override
            public List<To> newList() {
                return new ArrayList<To>();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to tell I'm working on java 7 and I'm looking for a java 5+ solution. 
Thanks for your reply anyway :)

Comment: @TitoZoeChiacchiera Then you can replace the `Supplier` by an interface of yourself and use  anonymous inner classes instead of method references or lambda expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, the question is tagged as [java-5](/questions/tagged/java-5). But if it wasn't, you could add a version such as

```
public abstract class ListConverter<From,To> implements Converter<From,To> {

    public List<To> convertList(List<From> fromList){
        … // as before
    }

    public List<To> convertList(List<From> fromList, Supplier<List<To>> supplier){
        if (fromList == null) {return null;}
        List<To> toList = supplier.get();

        for(From from: fromList ){
            toList.add(this.convert(from));
        }

        return toList;
    }

    public static <From,To> ListConverter<From, To> extend(final Converter<From, To> converter){
        return (From from) -> converter.convert(from);
    }
}
```

This one gets a `Supplier` which gives an ArrayList upon request. So you can call it with

```
convertList(myList, LinkedList::new);
```

in order to get a LinkedList instead of an ArrayList.

BTW, if you become accustomed to the Streams API, you don't need this ListConverter. You can just take the list and do

```
list.stream().map(converter::convert).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

or, as needed,

```
list.stream().map(converter::convert).collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply: I miss to say that I need a java 5+ solution. I will edit my question.